# How to override font for a specific theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to set a specific font to be used for a certain VSCode theme? That is, every time I enable the theme, I want a particular font to be used for the editor, but revert to the default if I switch to any other theme.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to raeach to theme's codes where font is specifed. Changing the block with the font attritubute will change corresponding theme's font but when you change to any other theme, font would be changed accordingly as you wished.